Car repo issue, car in distant state, what would likely happen?
My acquaintance in the US, Steve is early 20s and his Mom "gave" him a pickup, this a couple yrs ago, but the Mom still has the entire title/loan. There are no cosigners etc. This in I believe Florida /near there region. The bloke works in Alaska (he drove it up there at some point) and now, you guessed it, Mom had troubles and stopped paying a few months ago so $4000 is owing on the loan and the bank wants to repo it.  I don't need to tell you something is anyway broken on the truck which would be a $3-4k repair. (The truck would sell for 7k-10k at carmax. God knows how much is owing on it.)  The bloke as it happens is returning to the South (say, next month) but, of course, the truck is not drivable long-distances now without the repair in question.
Really I'm just plain nosy,

Would the bank repo it in Alaska? Is that a situation they commonly deal with, truck in another state?  (I guess AK/HI the worst possible cases!)

I would imagine there is NO mechanism where, Steve could sell it (ie, on the mother's behalf) to say his mechanic mate Biff for a few dollars and then the $ would flow to the bank, ie, I assume, there's no way lenders would be involved in that sort of deal (ie "Here, we'll trust you with the title whilst you sell it to Biff...!")

Since Steve is leaving AK imminently, it's hard to see other than the vehicle being basically abandoned there, with no owner. Basically I'm wondering if in repo situations, lenders have "repo collection points" in all states or ??

It seems in this situation all the Moms will be able to say to the lenders is "well the truck is stuck in AK, it doesn't run, Steve's already left AK and I don't know what to tell you" - really would the lender just put it deeper and deeper in collection, like any other uncollectible debt??  is a "car loan" in the US basically a personal loan (no collateral) {other than the somewhat comic collateral that is "some old car"} ...? Would bankruptcy be inevitable or is it unlikely for auto loans??

For you insider experts, what would realistically happen in this situation? Wild stuff!


I've only ever had a couple auto loans, in the US, anbd they were just paid off etc. uneventfully. Other than that all I know is what I've seen in the movie Repo-man !

Your friend should also be aware that Alaska is pretty sick of people abandoning cars, so simply abandoning the car could come back to bite them. Probably really only an issue in Anchorage and Fairbanks, but he or his mother could get dinged for the cost of disposing of the car. Out in the boonies the most likely result is that whoever's property he leaves the car on will claim title if they care to.

@CharlesE.Grant good point, TY.  It strikes me that I literally don't know how they could "get rid of it".  The mother can't sell it due to the repo, nor just give it away, and obviously the cost to just ship it to the South would be absurd, and as you say can't just "jingle key" it.  Wild!


Would the bank repo it in Alaska? Is that a situation they commonly deal with, truck in another state? (I guess AK/HI the worst possible cases!)

Possible. They can (and probably will) sell the debt to someone else who'd deal with the mechanics (no pun intended) of the repo process.

Steve could sell it ... I assume, there's no way lenders would be involved in that sort of deal

Why not? They only care about their money back. The Mom could call them up and ask them how'd they'd go about it, probably with some escrow involved. It's easier if the buyer uses financing and the financing companies arrange the title transfer between themselves, I've actually done that once (although with no delinquency involved).

Would bankruptcy be inevitable or is it unlikely for auto loans??

Yes, it is possible. While the car is a collateral, the debt is a recourse debt and the bank/debt collector can come after other assets if the car doesn't provide enough value to repay the debt. They will come after whoever signed the note, Mom in this case.

littleadv.  Thanks for that. You know, I might just delete the Q since, for whatever reason it seems to be downvoted, but thanks.  recourse debt!

I don't know why it's being down voted, maybe because you have multiple questions in there, but it's a reasonable question IMHO
